# Error while Uploading Model Explainations using Azure-Interpret ExplanationClient

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

We are trying to use Azure Machine Learning to interpret a model by using Azure ML Interpretability libraries namely **azureml-interpret**  and **azureml-sdk[explain]**.
Our model is RandomForestRegressor from sklearn.ensemble.

```
import lightgbm
from interpret.ext.blackbox import PFIExplainer
#from interpret.ext.glassbox import DecisionTreeExplainableModel
from azureml.contrib.interpret.explanation.explanation_client import ExplanationClient
model = train_model(X_train_df,y_train_df)

explainer = PFIExplainer(model, features = feature_names)

global_explanation = explainer.explain_global(X_test_df[0:50],true_labels=y_test_df[0:50])

explain_client = ExplanationClient.from_run(run)
explain_client.upload_model_explanation(global_explanation)
```

We are getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "training/train.py", line 83, in <module>
    explain_client.upload_model_explanation(global_explanation)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_d5d57a45ca9af991b8408524822c201f/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/interpret/_internal/explanation_client.py", line 793, in upload_model_explanation
    asset_type=History.ASSET_TYPE
TypeError: create_asset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'asset_type'
```

We have tried -
TabularExplainer, MimicExplainer(with DecisionTreeExplainableModel) but all of them result in the same error.

Comment: you can raise an issue in interpretml community to check by the team https://github.com/interpretml/interpret-community/issues. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-contrib-interpret/azureml.contrib.interpret.explanation.explanation_client.explanationclient?view=azure-ml-py#upload-model-explanation-explanation--max-num-blocks-none--block-size-none--top-k-none--comment-none--init-dataset-id-none--eval-dataset-id-none--ys-pred-dataset-id-none--ys-pred-proba-dataset-id-none--upload-datasets-false--model-id-none--true-ys-none--visualization-points-5000-